# How to set multiple envrionment variables with Chefs Systemd_unit resource?

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra, systemd

My task is to install a tomcat via chef. The only problem is, that my systemd_file (`tomcat.service`) is implemented via the chef resource `systemd_unit`. However, once I converge, the log warns me, that the key `Environment` is duplicated and therefore overwritten.
In my older version, I simply implemented my `tomcat.service` file via the `cookbook_file` resource by chef, and it worked perfectly.

Where is the problem? **How** do I implement multiple `Envrionment`-variables in the `systemd_unit` resource?

```
systemd_unit service_file do
  content({Unit: {
    Description: 'Apache Tomcat Web Application Container',
    After: 'syslog.target network.target',
  },
  Service: {
    Type: 'forking',
    Environment: 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre',
    Environment: 'CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid',
    Environment: 'CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat',
    Environment: 'CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat',
    Environment: 'CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC',
    Environment: 'JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom',
    Environment: 'PWM_APPLICATIONPATH=/opt/pwm-data',
    ExecStart: '/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh',
    ExecStop: '/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID',

    User:tuser,
    Group:tgroup,
    UMask:'0007',
    RestartSec:'10',
    Restart:'always',
  },
  Install: {
    WantedBy: 'multi-user.target',
  }})
  action :create
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is, it looks like chef elements are a dictionary will single value keys rather than an order multikey dictionary.  Looking at systemd docs it a space separated variables like `Environment: 'JAVA_HOME=... CATALINA_PID=...  PWM_APPLICATION=/top/pwm-data'` might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_systemd_unit.html#properties) helps.
`repeatable options can be implemented with an array.`

That means i need to write

```
Environment: ['JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java', 'CATALINA_HOME=some/path', 'and so on']
```